# reseting mysql root password

Tags: mysql

Is there a mysql command to reset the root password?

I am trying

```
 mysql -p -u root
```

but I've forgotten the password.

Is there any way to reset the password?

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html.

Comment: With a name like "All is well" you really shouldn't have these issues.

Answer (score 5):

Check the doc http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html

Basically this should be

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass')
    ->                   WHERE User='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Password is required first to run this query

Comment: You need to run it as start-up SQL for the database daemon - read the link.

Answer (score 4):

You can start the mysql-daemon with the argument --skip-grant-tables, then you can login without prompt and alter passwords.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-password.html

Answer (score 2):

see this

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have never set a root password for MySQL, the server does not require a password at all for connecting as root. To setup root password for first time, use mysqladmin command at shell prompt as follows:

```
$ mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
```

However, if you want to change (or update) a root password, then you need to use following command

For example, If old password is abc, and set new password to 123456, enter:

```
$ mysqladmin -u root -p'abc' password '123456'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Password is required first to run this query