# Accidently locked myself out of MySQL by changing the host

Tags: mysql, root

While trying to get remote MySQL working, I somehow managed to lock myself out with the root account.

Normally, I would stop the MySQL service and restart it using `/etc/init.d/mysql --init-file`, but when I try to do that, it says the script has been converted to an upstart job and to use the "service mysql" command. Unfortunately, as far as I know, the `service` command doesn't support the `--init-file` option.

Is there any other way to reset the host for the root user?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/210677/reseting-mysql-root-password

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stop MySQL:

```
service mysqld stop
```

then start MySQL like this

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
```

At this point you should be able to connect to mysql (from the local machine) as root.

Comment: You could also `service mysqld restart --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking`. Then, after fixing root, `service mysql restart`. Nonetheless, +1 !!!

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, that option wil be passed to `mysqld_safe`; the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html) describes this in detail. You may be able to discover how upstart is invoking MySQL, and then start it manually in similar way with your added `--init-file` option. Make sure you start it up as the right user, however!

If you're using Debian or Ubuntu, you will probably find that there is a root-equivalent `debian-sys-maint` user which you may be able to use temporarily; you'll find the automatically generated password for that in `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`. There may be alternatives on other systems, too? This option would probably be easier,