# reset root password in mysql without access to mysql table

Tags: mysql, osx-lion, localhost

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [reseting mysql root password](https://serverfault.com/questions/210677/reseting-mysql-root-password)

I am having an issue on OS X 10.7.5 as I used to use MAMP but for .htaccess issues I am now using my own compiled local server from a long time ago, the problem is i forgot the root password for mysql.

I have tried updating the password through terminal using mysql -u root, but I get this error message -> `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to find `mysql_secure_install` and run it. This script will allow you to reset root password among all other things.

Possible paths is

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If this script has already been run once, then it will prompt you for the current password with the OP doesn't know.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql -u root` attempts to login as the root user with no password (which won't work if a password is set, as one would hope).  To login, you either need to specify the [`-p`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_password) flag and provide the current password; or else see [Resetting the Root Password: Unix Systems](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-unix).

Comment: Ok, to fix the issue I just did a clean install of mysql as I had no databases that I needed.